# how do I get a cte function to work in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

```
WITH RECURSIVE CalculatedDate AS
(
SELECT LowerBoundDate AS Date
FROM TempDateDimension
UNION ALL

SELECT (Date + INTERVAL '1 DAY')
FROM CalculatedDate
WHERE (Date + INTERVAL '1 DAY') <= UpperBoundDate
)
;
--insert each date to our temporay dimension table
, TempDateDimension AS
(
    SELECT 
        Date AS Date_Key,
        TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'Month DD, YYYY') AS Full_Date_Name,
        MONTH(Date) AS Month_Id,
        TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'Month YYYY') AS Month_Name,
        DATE_PART('QUARTER', Date) AS Quarter_Id,
        CONCAT('Quarter ', DATE_PART('QUARTER', Date), ' ', TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'YYYY')) AS Quarter_Name,
        YEAR(Date) AS Year_Id,
        TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'YYYY') AS Year_Name,
        TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'DAYNAME') AS Day_Name,
        DATE_PART('DOY', Date) AS Day_Of_Year,
        CASE 
            WHEN TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'DAYNAME') = 'Sunday' THEN 0
            WHEN TO_VARCHAR(Date, 'DAYNAME') = 'Saturday' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS WorkDay
    FROM CalculatedDate
);
```

was expecting to work but keeps giving me a ";" error

Comment: Your code looks like `WITH RECURSIVE CalculatedDate as (...), TempDateDimension  as (...);`. So there are two CTEs but not actual outer query (`select`, `insert`, `update`, ...). What is the purpose of your query?

Comment: Thinking you are missing something because you have ;  then a ,  So the ; is probably the error.

Comment: When someone says `;` is the problem, first thing you do is remove it and try. dont you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "snowflake" but if the error is a semicolon using cte, try putting the semicolon before the reserve word "WITH", the semicolon will be used to specify that your cte expression starts there `;WITH RECURSIVE CalculatedDate AS ...`

Comment: no he has a semicolon between two cte s and at the end belongs a SELECT,INSERt, UPDATE,